# How to apply magento default form validation in homepage?

Tags: magento-1.8, form-validation

I have one form in hader.phtml of magento.I have added the following line after form and used `class="required-entry"` for applying validation. In all other pages validtaion is working.But in homepage its not working.can anyone help me.

`<script type="text/javascript">
//< ![CDATA[
  var myForm= new VarienForm('new_login', true);
//]]>
</script>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the Below Steps.

`First create the form.`

```
<form id="form-id" action="" method="post">
  <label for="name" class="required"><?php echo $this->__('Name'); ?></label>
      <div class="input-box">
          <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value="" class="input-text required-entry">
      </div>       
</form>
```

`Then add the Below Code.`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
     var dataForm = new VarienForm('form-id', true);
    //]]>
</script>
```

Check and Enjoy the validation
Make sure Form Id and `VarienForm` name will be same.

Comment: Its is working fine in all other pages.Only in my homepage its not working.

Comment: strange.............

Comment: I have used Responsivebanner slider for homepage slider.Its because of that.Is it possible to resolve it?

Comment: try to solve the jQuery conflict.